# Reorder factor levels to display correctly in facet wrapped bar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to reorder the levels in my variable "response" so they show in the correct order on my bar charts. The order of levels should be "yes", "no" and "less than one year", "one year", "greater than one year". However, when I try to reorder them using the factor() function some of my variable levels are replaced with NA.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(scales)

percent <- c(0.20, .56, .36, .36, .78, .64, 0.20)
response <- c(rep(c("yes", "no"), 2), c("less than one year", "one year", "greater than one year"))
question <- c(rep("dogs",2), rep("cats",2), rep("years at home",3)) 

survey <- data.frame(percent, response, question) %>% 
  mutate(response = str_wrap(response, width = 8)) %>% 
  mutate(response = factor(response, levels = c("yes", "no", "less than one year", "one year", "greater than one year")))

ggplot(survey, aes(x=response, y=percent)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
  geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent(percent),
                y= percent), position = position_dodge(width = 1), vjust = -.5) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 1.1,0.2),
                     limits = c(0,1.1),
                     labels=percent_format(accuracy = 1),
                     expand = c(0,0)) +
  labs(title = "",
       x = "",
       y = "Percentage") +
  facet_wrap(~question, scales = "free") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(family = "sans", 
                                  face = "bold", 
                                  hjust = 0.5, 
                                  size = 14, 
                                  margin = margin(0,0,10,0)),
        axis.text = element_text(family = "sans",
                                 size = 11),
        axis.text.y = element_text(margin = margin(0,0,0,5),
                                   size = 12),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 12,
                                   angle = 0,
                                   margin = margin(5,0,0,0)),
        axis.title.x = element_text(family = "sans",
                                    size = 14,
                                    margin = margin(10,0,0,0)),
        axis.title.y = element_text(family = "sans",
                                    size = 14),
        plot.caption = element_text(hjust = 0.5, vjust = -1.0, size = 12, 
                                    margin = margin(4,0,0,0)),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        strip.text = element_text(size = 11, face = "bold"))
```

Comment: The visualization you've uploaded doesn't match the output from your code - as you say in the question, the code adds NAs. The visualization does not have any,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values in your response variable need to be called as "less\nthan one\nyear" and "greater\nthan one\nyear" because they include new line ("\n") characters. This should solve the issue!

```
survey <- data.frame(percent, response, question) %>% 
  mutate(response = str_wrap(response, width = 8)) %>% 
  mutate(response = factor(response, levels = c("no", "yes", "less\nthan one\nyear", "one year", "greater\nthan one\nyear")))
```

If this still didn't provide the correct order, you could add `as.ordered = T` as an option in your factor function, but the above example seems to work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the order in which you mutate will remove the NA problem:

instead of:

```
survey <- data.frame(percent, response, question) %>% 
  mutate(response = str_wrap(response, width = 8)) %>% 
  mutate(response = factor(response, levels = c("yes", "no", "less than one year", "one year", "greater than one year")))
```

Use

```
survey <- data.frame(percent, response, question) %>% 
  mutate(response = factor(response, levels = c("yes", "no", "less than one year", "one year", "greater than one year"))) %>% 
  mutate(response = str_wrap(response, width = 8))
```

Comment: The answer by @Conner Sexton removes the NA problem (as does mine), and additionally orders the factor variable the way you want it.